# Using contains() function with selenium on Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, contains

I'm trying to use contains function on selenium and trying to do a certain action if that specific text exists and click on it.

How to use contains function with `driver.find.element()`.
So far I tried:

```
if driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, contains("Hello World")) == True:
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Hello World").click()
```

and some variations of it.

Element:

```
<a href="/xyz" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm leading-4 font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">"Hello World"</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use contains():

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//*[contains(.,'Hello World')]")
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//*[contains(text(),'Hello World')]")
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//*[contains(@id,'Hello World')]")
```

Syntax:

```
//tagName[contains(@attribute_name,'attribute_value')]
```

or

```
//*[contains(@attribute_name,'attribute_value')]
```

or

```
//*[contains(text(),'value')]
```

Comment: Hello it has ' in it so its more like Hell'o World how can I do with that way sorry for misleading

Comment: Put a slash before that like: Hell\'o World

Answer (score 0):

There's the `By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT` selector option that can do substrings of link text.

Comment: But it comes up at certain times it Im trying to use it in while i<10:
    if driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT("url")) == True:
        driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT("url")).click()
    else:
        driver.find_element("id","step_button").click()
        time.sleep(15)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `driver.find_elements` method, not `driver.find_element` because in case of no such element found `driver.find_element` will throw exception, it will not return a Boolean False.
While `driver.find_elements` will return a **list** of matching web elements. In case there were matches found it will return a non-empty list, and it will be interpreted by Python as Boolean True. Otherwise, if no matches found, it will return an empty string, and it will be interpreted by Python as Boolean False.
As mentioned by AbiSaran you can use `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,` and in case the string contains `'` you can use a slash as following"

```
if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'fellow\'s world')]"):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'fellow\'s world')]").click()
```

Or

```py
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'fellow\'s world')]")
if elements:
    elements[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that rather than using `contains()` function I simply used

```
def xyz():
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='h-10']")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

to check if that specific class, button, etc. exists and creating while, if functions to make decisions.

For example:

```
i = 0
while i<10:
    xyz()
    if xyz() == True:
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    else:
        abc()
```